# Database index error when importing contact entity in crm 2011 organisation

Tags: dynamics-crm, crm, dynamics-crm-2011, solution, microsoft-dynamics

Our company has a crm 2011 dev environment and some customers. I recently exported a solution which contained the contact entity from dev and tried to import it in an other organisation (one of our customers). At approx 30% import i get the following error;

"One of the fields of the selected entity is a part of database index and so it cannot be greater than 900 bytes."

..on the contact entity.

Log file:

```
1.0
Unmanaged

DefaultPublisherhc
Default Publisher for hc
Default publisher for this organization

Failure
One of the fields of the selected entity is a part of database index and so it cannot be greater than 900 bytes.
34.62
42.2
```

This organisation runs on a partner hosted server.
Anyone a clue what the problem (and solution) could be?

Thanks in advance,

Kind regards

Angelo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this a fresh new organization, or have there already been some customizations to it? If you have access to the SQL box, I'd check for any indexes on the ContactBase or ContactExtensionBase tables and remove them.

I'd also check your customizations... did you increase the maximum length of any native text attributes above 900 characters? Try dialing those back if you can and reimport.